# How to have persistence with NSUserDefault?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I wish to save a simple username via:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("UncleRic", forKey:"username")
```

But when I return, particularly via re-activation of the app, I get nothing:

> (lldb) po gUserDefault.objectForKey("username") as? String
>   nil

Here's the simple code:

```
import UIKit

let gUserDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let userName = gUserDefault.objectForKey("username") as? String
let password = gUserDefault.objectForKey("password") as? String


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("UncleRic", forKey:"username")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I want to be able to access the User Default's values from the AppDelegate as well as from a UIViewcontroller.

How can I make this thing persistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to `gUserDefault.setObject...` and when you're done saving, call `gUserDefault.synchronize()`

Comment: And you usually shouldn't call synchronize on NSUserDefaults after every save. iOS calls it automatically when the app is closed. However, if you need to access the value before the app is closed, use it.

Comment: That's not accurate either. You never need to synchronize within one process on modern versions of iOS. You only use it if you're about to call exit() after setting a preference (like… in less than a millisecond or so), or if you're about to notify another process to read that preference.

Comment: That's what the documentation says. But in my experience, calling synchronize is necessary if you're accessing the value before the app is closed and reopened. That's just what I've observed.

Comment: If the app is terminated (via the user killing it, or more commonly for us developers, by killing it with Xcode) then the user defaults don't get saved.

Comment: Okay.... so I can store simple strings in NSUserDefault that remain persistent as long as the app isn't killed; i.e., services hibernation.  Persistence thru death would require a plist or other physical file.

Comment: Sort of. If you definitely need the value to persist immediately, call synchronize on the defaults object. But use synchronize sparingly.

Comment: And if my answer works, please accept it so I get credit.